# Is there a way to test a formula result in excel and type it only once, all within one cell and not using a user defined function?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

Given the formula:

```
 =if(a1+b2+c4+g3+b4>10,"No",a1+b2+c4+g3+b4)
```

Is there any way to not have to type the same a1+b2+c4+g3+b4 twice and have the results be either "No" or the value of a1+b2+c4+g3+b4?

Something like:

```
 =???(a1+b2+c4+g3+b4,">10","No")
```

Seems like I'm always entering the same formula twice when wanting to test the value and if the value is some condition then the results are one thing, otherwise it's the results of the formula

Comment: Use [Let](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/let-function-34842dd8-b92b-4d3f-b325-b8b8f9908999)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the Let function:

```
=LET(Value,A1+B2+C4+G3+B4,IF(Value>10,"No",Value))
```

Note that you don't have to call it 'Value', you can name `A1+B2+C4+G3+B4` anything